# @OneToOne from two classes to same class

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

For better understanding, I want to achieve this:

[image: External Account example]

**Note:** Buyer may not have ExternalAccount but Seller must have it. What I have/tried:

Buyer Class:

```
@Entity
public class Buyer extends User {

    @OneToOne(optional=true, cascade= {CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(nullable=true)
    private ExternalAccount externalAccount;
    //getters and setters

}
```

Seller Class:

```
@Entity
public class Seller extends User {

    @OneToOne(optional=false, cascade= {CascadeType.MERGE})
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(nullable=false)
    private ExternalAccount externalAccount;
    //getters and setters and other properties

}
```

ExternalAccount class:

```
@Entity
public class ExternalAccount {

    @Id
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Long id;
    //getters and setters

}
```

I am using Spring Data JPA with Spring Boot and I want that:

- If there's no Buyer related but ExternalAccount exists (associated with Seller), associate it.
- If there's no Seller related but ExternalAccount exists (associated with Buyer), associate it.
- If no ExternalAccount exists, when saving Buyer/Seller, creates the ExternalAccount.

I could achieve similar behavior with `CascadeType.MERGE` (after reading a lot of posts of Stackoverflow), but using this it doesn't respect `@OneToOne` mapping. It allows to create a lot of Buyers related to the same ExternalAccount.

- I've created a github project with the database tests to reproduce the issue.

https://github.com/ralphavalon/jpa-mapping

There, I have my example rest controllers (MappingController):

```
//Creating buyer example
@RequestMapping(value = "/newBuyer", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public Object newBuyer() {
    Buyer buyer = new Buyer();
    buyer.setBirthdate(LocalDateTime.now());
    buyer.setEmail("buyer@email.com");
    buyer.setName("Buyer Name");
    ExternalAccount external = new ExternalAccount();
    external.setId(123L);
    buyer.setExternalAccount(external);
    buyerDao.save(buyer);
    return buyer;
}

//Creating seller example
@RequestMapping(value = "/newSeller", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public Object newSeller() {
    Seller seller = new Seller();
    seller.setBirthdate(LocalDateTime.now());
    seller.setEmail("seller@email.com");
    seller.setName("Seller Name");
    ExternalAccount external = new ExternalAccount();
    external.setId(123L);
    seller.setExternalAccount(external);
    sellerDao.save(seller);
    return seller;
}
```

When I call `/newBuyer` at the first time, it saves. Now, if I call `/newSeller` after calling `/newBuyer` it returns this:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.EXTERNAL_ACCOUNT(ID)"; SQL statement:
insert into external_account (id) values (?) [23505-196]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.EXTERNAL_ACCOUNT(ID)"; SQL statement:
insert into external_account (id) values (?) [23505-196]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345) ~[h2-1.4.196.jar:1.4.196]
```

Comment: What if you move the externalAccount relationship to the User class?  (where it should be nullable because a buyer may not have an account)

Comment: Then in theory I could have Seller without ExternalAccount... This will probably be my way out, but I wanted something closer to that approach. It's semantically right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with these changes:

- Changing the mapping of the classes:

**Buyer** class:

```
@Entity
public class Buyer extends User {

    @OneToOne(optional=true, cascade= {CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(nullable=true, unique=true)
    private ExternalAccount externalAccount;
    //getters and setters

}
```

**Seller** class:

```
@Entity
public class Seller extends User {

    @OneToOne(optional=false, cascade= {CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(nullable=false, unique=true)
    private ExternalAccount externalAccount;
    //getters and setters

}
```

**ExternalAccount** class:

```
@Entity
public class ExternalAccount {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    //getters and setters

}
```

And the most important part: **Override Spring Data JPA save method** to use `entityManager.merge`

```
@Service
public class BuyerService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public Buyer save(Buyer buyer) {
        return entityManager.merge(buyer);
    }

}
```

And the same thing with SellerService.